# Make main thread wait until URLRequest finishes

Tags: multithreading, swift3, ios10

I am trying to hold execution until URLRequest is done.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    self.sendRequest(request: request as URLRequest) {
        }
    self.firebaseAuth(credential)
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: SEGUE_TO_FIRST_CONTENT_PAGE, sender: nil)

}

func sendRequest (request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        do {
            let userData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:[]) as? [String:AnyObject]
            let genderData = userData!["gender"] as! String
            self.userObject.gender = genderData
            completion()
        } catch {
            completion()
            print("ERROR")
        }
        print("sendRequest Done!")
        }.resume()
}
```

Right now, it performs segue even before finishing sendRequest(). I can't figure out how to make main thread wait til sendRequest() is done.

Comment: Why not just perform the segue side the block?

Comment: It doesn't allow you to edit UI outside main thread.

Comment: Wrap the call in a main queue async it's a common pattern.

Comment: I tried that, but no luck. I would really appreciate it if you can give me some kind of pseudo code..

Comment: Maybe if you showed what you tried...

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.sendRequest(request: request as URLRequest) {}
        } This is what I tried. I have also tried using DipathQueue.main.sync

Comment: Not the whole method, just the bits that have to run on the main thread.

Comment: I tried that as well, doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: i tried enclosing session.dataTask into main async.

Comment: That's not going to help because the completion block will run on a background queue.

Comment: I figured it out the hard way.. I did this.                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: SEGUE_TO_FIRST_CONTENT_PAGE, sender: nil)
                } Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the completion handler to pass the request status and perform action in completion handler based on the status.If the operation is anything to do with UI , then wrap that in main thread.Sample below

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    self.sendRequest(request: request as URLRequest){ (loginStatus) in
        if loginStatus {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.firebaseAuth(credential)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: SEGUE_TO_FIRST_CONTENT_PAGE, sender: nil)
            }
        }
        else{
            //Handle Error case
        }
    }

}

func sendRequest (request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
        do {
            let userData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:[]) as? [String:AnyObject]
            let genderData = userData!["gender"] as! String
            self.userObject.gender = genderData
            completion(true)
        } catch {
            completion(false)
            print("ERROR")
        }
        print("sendRequest Done!")
        }.resume()
}
```